# Colored lines in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add a vertical line as an indicator to each RecyclerView item (besides the normal horizontal ones). A plain view is used for this as done by the "Layout Designer" of Android Studio. As long as the item layout is displayed in the designer, everything is working fine, but the indicator is not visible in the emulator after building the application.

This is the relevant section from the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/myDefault"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#0000ff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is a clash between RelativeLayout's height=wrapContent and the indicator view's height=matchParent.

Change your indicator view like so, to get its height from the entry view, which has an actual height, defined by its text content.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/entry"
    android:background="#0000ff" />
```